# Static method of singleton class used in multiple activities

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, static-methods

There is an asynckTask and 2 methods,which are being called by 2 activities.
i Want to keep the AsyncTask class and the methods inside myApplication class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

( which was needed anyway,had some states of app to be maintained).

One other way is to have those methods in each activity and the asyncTask as independent class.

what is the best way?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question is not clearly stated.

Comment: It is not required to keep that method static if you want to use it in multiple classes. You can also access them via objects. Static is required if you want same value throughout your app

Comment: the method is independent of instance.

Comment: @VivekMishra hey thanks,please check once i have changed my question.

Comment: You can't keep asynctask inside Application class

Comment: Can you post your code, or in case it's too complex, a simple example of what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

How about having a base activity class for that?
Something like:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected void myMethod() {
        // do what ever
    }
}
```

Then just extend this `BaseActivity` to have that method in your activities.